# iWebBrowser::Navigate Deadlock after a ole32.dll exception

Tags: c++, mfc, ole, freeze, iwebbrowser2

I have a question related to windows embedded browser and COM. What I am trying to do is to display some data to the user in a HTML form so I use the `iwebbrowser2` control to achieve this.

I have this weird deadlock or hang in my application after a call to `iwebbrowser2 Navigate` is made after a `ole32.dll` crash. This ole32 crash randomly happens in my application. There is not a usual place or time in which the exception happens. It could happen right in the beginning on the application execution or later on while using the application. The application that o work on has several threads running and some windows worker thread that just spawns out of nowhere. There is a particular thread called `WrapperThreadProc` that I'm not sure what is doing but it does a call to `CoUninitialize` on a COM object that might not exist anymore possibly causing the exception on the `ole32.dll` (not sure if this is actually happening).

**here are the pics of the call stack when the exception happens**
[image: here are the pics of the call stack when the exception happens]

**and here is a pic of the call stack when the deadlock happens after `navigate()`**
[image: and here is a pic of the call stack when the deadlock happens after navigate()]

Does anyone have a clue on what is going on with this wired issue? I do appreciate any small help.

Thanks

Comment: Screenshots are unreadable, and useless. Always post callstacks as text, and provide a [mcve]. With the information you provided, we can only suggest that you fix your bug(s).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will keep in mind all the suggestions next time I ask a question. With that being said, I have found the solution to the problem. It turns out that there is a race condition happening in the networkitemfactory.dll and Microsoft released a hotfix for it. Here is the article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2494427.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem. It turns out that there is a race condition happening in the networkitemfactory.dll that would cause the ole32.dll crash and unload. If any COM call is made after the exception like "iwebbrowser2::navigate" then application would hang in a deadlock. Microsoft released a hotfix for it. Here is the article support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2494427